# WAS 8.5.5.2 not able to connect to DB2 Datasource

Tags: db2, websphere, websphere-8

I am trying to test the datasource connection created on cluster in WebSphere 8.5.5.2 ND with DB2. As soon as I click on test connection button, WAS flashes me following message:

> The test connection operation failed for data source Temp on server
>   nodeagent at node MyNode001 with the following exception:
>   java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException:
>   [jcc][t4][2013][11249][4.16.53] Connection authorization failure
>   occurred. Reason: User ID or Password invalid. ERRORCODE=-4214,
>   SQLSTATE=28000 DSRA0010E: SQL State = 28000, Error Code = -4,214.

I checked everything, my username and password is correct and not expired. Driver files are also verified. I also tried restarting everything from deployment manager to node agents but still it displays me the same error

Comment: You say the username and password are valid, DB2 says they're not. Who do we trust?

Comment: I am able to connect to DB2 through squirrel using same Username and password. So in that case there is something wrong with the WAS

Comment: Restart server. It sometimes dont pick up alias after you define it. And make sure it is set in the Container managed alias. And double check, if you use same case in username and pass as in squirrel.

Comment: Forget it. I deleted data source entry and abbdded it back again it worked.